F# interface or derived class match
I can't wrap my head around thinking about why in F# derived class or interface implementation match works when the instance being matched against is an object, but not when it's some concrete type? What is the conceptual or other reason behind this?
For example, if we have such class hierarchy
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, ISomeInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod() => Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod");
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

Then this F# code would not compile
    member this.Execute(arg: BaseClass) =
        match arg with
        | :? ISomeInterface as derived -> derived.SomeMethod()
        | _ -> printfn "Not a derived class"

But this one would!
    member this.Execute(arg: BaseClass) =
        match arg :> obj with
        | :? ISomeInterface as derived -> derived.SomeMethod()
        | _ -> printfn "Not a derived class"

Are there any logical explanations for this compiler behaviour?

you should be able to cast with :> without needing to have an 'other' case. match is more about dealing with multiple possible outcomes - in your case, tehre's just one thing, and it happens to be convertible to base classes or interfaces.
Boxing it changes what you are doing to a very different operation.
something like (arg: ISomeInterface).SomeMethod() or let ai: ISomeInterface = arg in ai.SomeMethod() (dont have a link but the bottom line is that F# does not implicitly convert to an interface, though it will do it e.g. if passing it as an argument and/or if you are returning it

Hm, the above missed the point that BaseClass is unrelated to ISomeInterface; As the answer correctly points out, F#'s :? doesnt allow such checks on arbitrary type pairs (that don't have a static relationship. The fact that matchwon't allow it without boxing is to guide you toward the static check if it's possible. (When I say boxing, I'm referring to the CLR operation of that name - see also the F#boxoperator, which is related to your:> obj` construct)

This is because the spec said so.
The F# language spec is a formal description that aspired to be current with F# compiler development into the 2015-2016 timeframe. Tweaks thereafter are dealt with via RFCs.

7.9 Dynamic Type-Test Patterns
... An error occurs if type cannot be statically determined to be a subtype of the type of the pattern input.

This doesn't only affect dynamic type-test patterns but also dynamic type-test expressions of the form expr :? ty. Consider:
type ISomeInterface = abstract SomeMethod : unit -> unit
type BaseClass() = class end
type DerivedClass() =
    inherit BaseClass()
    interface ISomeInterface with member __.SomeMethod() = ()

BaseClass() :? ISomeInterface // doesn't compile
BaseClass() :> obj :? ISomeInterface // evaluates to false
DerivedClass() :> obj :? ISomeInterface // evaluates to true


But this spec quote doesn't really make much sense to me, since when you cast an instance to obj it doesn't make the type statically determinable, and yet it starts compiling. E.g. it looks like making the instance type less statically determinable leads to the compiler suddenly being OK with the type test.

@Shorstok The static determination of the type dynamically tested against being a subtype of the pattern input type happens through constraint solving, we're getting a Type constraint mismatch if it is not. By upcasting all the way to the root of the object hierarchy, or by boxing, the constraint is resolved. Note that the spec itself has numerous examples of doing exactly this in conjunction with dynamic type tests.

I still don't get it - how does type Object resolve the constraint that Interface is a subtype (?...), where some other arbitrary SomeClass does not? It's not like "we can be sure that Object can definitely implement said interface, and SomeClass can't", the chances are the same.
And strictly speaking, interfaces are not in the type hierarchy, since in the CLI they are not derived from system.object.
